# How to retrieve file name for processed files using batch command?

Tags: batch-file

I am using `gdalsrsinfo` to extract the projection details of vector files in multiple folders using the code mentioned below:

```
for /R .\ %%f IN ("*.tab") DO gdalsrsinfo -o wkt "%%f" >>U:\srsinfo.csv
```

Though the output file has been created with the projection details, it's not listing the filenames. Output e.g.:

> ```
> GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 80",6378137,298.257222101],TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
> GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563],TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
> ```

Without filenames, I can't use this code. Is it possible to extract the respective filenames?

Comment: The filename is referenced by `%%f`. Where in the output do you want it?

Comment: `for /R .\ %%f IN ("*.tab") DO (echo File: %%f & gdalsrsinfo -o wkt "%%f") >>U:\srsinfo.csv`

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.